# How to assign order comment in comment column in sales order grid

Tags: orders

I'm trying to assign **customer comment** left in **checkout page** to comments column in sales grid.

I can see comment column and tried different cases none of them working.

Can you advice how to assign this?

Comment: write more about it, it's not clear enough.